# UIWebView content size always returning the same value

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I've been stuck on this for hours now. I'm trying to dynamically resize a UIWebView based on it's content size. My problem is that everything works fine when I run my app on an iPhone 5, but I don't get the same behavior on an iPhone 4 (and on the simulator - 3.5 inch).

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview {

    CGFloat height = webview.scrollView.contentSize.height;
    _descriptionHeight = height;
    self.webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    self.webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
}
```

With this version of my code, on an iPhone 4, `height` is always equal to 0, no matter what the content is. I also tried calculating it with JS using

```
[[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.height"] floatValue]
```

but in this case, the returned value is ALWAYS 480 (which is the height of the screen).

Both methods work fine on an iPhone 5, the problem is only on the 4 (both running iOS6).

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
I managed to find a way to reproduce the problem. I have a table view with one section, 8 static cells. My webview is inside the 4th cell (starting from the top, row = 3). If my move my cell to the first position (row = 0), everything works fine. If I move it back to the 4th spot, I can reproduce my problem. What do you guys think it might be. A bug in UITableView?

Comment: I just tried out your code on an iPhone 4 (iOS6) and in the simulator (iOS5 & iOS6) and it works fine for me. I'm unable to recreate the problem you're having. The issue may be with how you are setting up the `UIWebView`, and not in `webViewDidFinishLoad:`. Sorry I cant help any more than that.

Comment: @StephSharp Thanks for trying. My webView is set in a storyboard, so maybe I'll just try to redo that screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. After looking at my screen, I ended up realizing that on an iPhone 5, the cell containing my `UIWebView` was shown when the screen would load, as with the iPhone 4, since the screen is smaller, I had to scroll a bit to see my cell.

I figured that, on the iPhone 4, since the web view wasn't visible initially, that's why I kept on getting funny results.

I ended up moving my `webView loadHTMLString:` selector in

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and everything works fine now.

So I managed to fixed my problem, but if someone could explain why you can't get the content size of a UIWebView if it's not currently visible, in a UITableView, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: `UITableView` only loads cells that are visible. The other cells are loaded as you scroll and they become visible. So if your `UIWebView` is in a cell that is not on screen, it will not have been loaded yet, hence a height of 0. In [Apple's doco for UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW16) it says `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` returns "An object representing a cell of the table or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range."

Comment: @StephSharp Thanks. I knew about a `UITableView` only loading the visible cells, but how come my `webViewDidFinishLoad` was still getting called?